# flatpicker1 onChange event to set minDate on flatpicker2. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I have just downloaded [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) which is a datetime picker in javascript.

A few quick references: [Examples](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/), [Formating tokens](https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/) & [Events](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/)

I am trying to figure out how to use 2 datetime pickers which need to depend on one another to avoid data range selection errors.

**So far I have:**

Made sure user can only choose dates in 2019.
The time for inputText1 is always 00:00:00.

**To do:**

Set inputText2 minDate equal to inputText1 minDate using inputText1 onChange event.

inputText2 times must always end in 23:59:59

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#inputText1").flatpickr({
    minDate: "2019-01",
    maxDate: "2019-12",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
    // When this input changes, we set a min start date for input2 always equal or greater than from date.
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      $("#reportFromCustom").html(dateStr);

      // Any ideas?
      //$("#inputText2").flatpickr({ minDate: dateStr });
    }

  });

  $("#inputText2").flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d 23:59:59",
    // When this input changes, we set a min start date for input2 always equal or greater than from date.
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      $("#reportToCustom").html(dateStr);
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>


<table>
  <th>
    <tr>
    <strong>Select range</strong>
    </tr>
  </th>
  <tr>
  <td>From: <input type="text" id="inputText1"></td>
  <td>To:<input type="text" id="inputText2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are searching for [`set()`](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#set-option-value) method

```
set(option, value)
```

```js
var date1 = $("#inputText1").flatpickr({
  minDate: "2019-01",
  maxDate: "2019-12",
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    date2.set('minDate', dateStr)
  }
});

var date2 = $("#inputText2").flatpickr({
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d 23:59:59",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    date1.set('maxDate', dateStr)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<table>
  <th>
    <tr>
      <strong>Select range</strong>
    </tr>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>From: <input type="text" id="inputText1"></td>
    <td>To:<input type="text" id="inputText2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing I was able to come up with this solution.

I have basically added a flatpicker inside of the onchange event of the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#reportCustomDisplay").html('Nothing Selected');

  // Initially always disabled.
  $("#inputText2").prop('disabled', true);

  // DATE FROM
  $("#inputText1").flatpickr({
    // First Month of year
    minDate: "2019-01-01",
    // Last  Month of year
    maxDate: "2019-12-31",
    // Format it to a mySQL datetime friendly format
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",

    // When this input changes, we set a min start date 
    // for input2 always equal or greater than this.
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {

      // Set display from
      $("#reportFromCustom").html(dateStr);
      // Enable inputText2
      $("#inputText2").prop('disabled', false);
      // Set display to
      $("#reportToCustom").html('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
      // Set display progress
      $("#reportCustomDisplay").html('..to when?');

      // Recreate inputText2 with relative start date
      $("#inputText2").flatpickr({ 
        // inputText1 selected datetime
        minDate: dateStr, 
        // Last  Month of year
        maxDate: "2019-12-31",
        // Format it to a mySQL datetime friendly format
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d 23:59:59", 
        onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
          // Set display to
          $("#reportToCustom").html(dateStr);
          // Set display progress
          $("#reportCustomDisplay").html('Click Get report!');
        }
      });
    }


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>


<table>
  <th>
    <tr>
    <strong>Select range v2</strong>
    </tr>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>From: <input type="text" id="inputText1"></td>
    <td>To:<input type="text" id="inputText2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Status:</strong> <span id="reportCustomDisplay"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>From: <span id="reportFromCustom"></span></td>
    <td>To: <span id="reportToCustom"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```